# Swift class does not retain the value in one of its properties

Tags: swift, class, equatable

I have multiple items of the class Product. I'm comparing the products based on the id and the variationId.

```
class Product: Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var variationId: Int
    var quantity: Int
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, variationId: Int, quantity: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.variationId = variationId
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
        return
            lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.variationId == rhs.variationId
    }
}
```

In the product view controller I have a struct VariationOption and a variable product as follows.

```
struct VariationOption {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var option: String
}

var product: Product!
```

When the user changes the color option, it changes the variationId property for that product

```
self.product.variationId = variationOption.id
```

The user can select a different color for the product and in doing so changes the variationId. When adding the product to the cart, the addItemToCart function checks if the product exists in the shopping cart. If the product exists, the quantity for that product id changes, otherwise the product gets added to the cart.

What I'm trying to do is compare the variation id and if it is different also add the product to the cart.

The problem I'm having is this. The user selects an option, the variation id changes, the product is being added to the cart but instead of adding a new product it is changing the variation id to the product already in the cart products array.

How can I make sure the product inside the products array in the shopping cart does not change the variation id property?

```
func addItemToCart(product: Product) {
    if let cartItemIndex = cartItems.firstIndex(of: product) {
        cartItems[cartItemIndex].quantity += product.quantity
    } else {
        cartItems.append(product)
    }
}
```

Comment: use a struct instead of a class

Comment: I think your `Product` type is ill-defined. It seems to be trying to play two different roles simultaneously: a product as found in a product catalogue, and a product as in a line item of an order/shopping-cart/invoice. If you split the two responsibilities, you'll find there's no need to mutate the variant ID. A `Product` has an array of variants, and both the product and the variants are immutable descriptions of the products for sale. A `LineItem` can contain a specfici product variant, with no need for it to be mutable

Comment: The code you provided is working fine, I tried it with few `Products`, and it always makes a correct decision whether to update quantity or append. So something else is amiss. 
I suggest adding Unit Tests to have more confidence in your code. And then concentrating on other parts: maybe you think you re passing the same instance of `cartItems` array somewhere, except arrays are passed by value?